# Multi-Language-require.js project - optimize with r.js

Tags: internationalization, requirejs, local-storage, r.js

In our project we are using require.js for the module definition. The web project also provides multi-language support. For that case we use the require.js bundle i18n. Everything works until the optimization with r.js is processed.

In the main.js file we have defined the following lines of code

```
config: {
    i18n: {
        locale: localStorage.getItem('locale') || 'de-de'
    }
}
```

So it is possible for the user to switch the language. Somewhere in the code we have that:

```
    'click .lang-selection' : function(ev){
        localStorage.setItem('locale',$(ev.currentTarget).attr('data-language'));
        location.reload();
    }
```

But when it comes down to the optimization part with r.js, a problem occurs.

*Error: Error: The config in mainConfigFile /home/ch/html5-app/src/web/main.js cannot be used because it cannot be evaluated correctly while running in the optimizer. Try only using a config that is also valid JSON, or do not use mainConfigFile and instead copy the config values needed into a build file or command line arguments given to the optimizer.
    at Function.createConfig (/home/ch/html5-app/bin/r.js:24283:23)*

Does anybody have a solution for that or even another approach? For example building an own optimized file for each language?

in addition the js.build.js file

```
    ({
    baseUrl: "../",
    name: "src/web/main",
    paths: {
        // require.js
        requirejs : 'vendor/backbone/require.215',
        // app specific modules
        root: 'src/web/app/js',
        templates : 'src/web/app/templates',
        // shared modules
        shared: 'src/shared/app/js',
        confighandler : 'src/shared/app/js/config/confighandler',
        root_config : 'src/web/app/js/config/config',
        layout: 'src/shared/app/js/views/layout',
        general: 'src/shared/app/js/general',
        helper: 'src/shared/app/js/helper',
        session: 'src/shared/app/js/session',
        vent: 'src/shared/app/js/vent',
        view: 'src/shared/app/js/views',
        model: 'src/shared/app/js/models',
        module : 'src/shared/app/js/modules',
        collection: 'src/shared/app/js/collections',
        nls : 'empty:',
        facebookSDK: 'empty:'
    },
    mainConfigFile: '../src/web/main.js',
    preserveLicenseComments: false,
    stubModules : ['text'],
    inlineText: true,
    // optimize: 'none',
    include: ['requirejs']
})
```

Comment: updated to version 2.18 without success, still got the same error.